# Center Image in Bootstrap Navbar with no overlap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to figure out two issues.

1.
There's a lot of examples I've seen on how to center an image in the middle of a bootstrap navbar, however, I'm having issues figuring out how to prevent the image from overlapping links when the screen is shrunk down to a smaller size (without triggering hamburger menu)

Example:
[JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/blobula/9zLLmt8v/)

If you shrink the screen down slowly you will see the center icon overlap the 'Reporting' link. How do I prevent this from happening? Is there a way for the image to recognize the edge of the last link and no overlap it?

2.
Is there a way for the navbar to resize in height based on the height of the image instead of the image overlapping the navbar?

Code:

```
<style>
 .navbar-brand.navbar-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
 }
 .navbar-toggle {
 z-index:3;
 }
 </style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class=""><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">My Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Administration</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Reporting <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>


  <a class="navbar-brand navbar-center" href="http://disputebills.com"><img height="78" width="78" style="margin-right: 10px; padding: 0;" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/disputebills/image/upload/v1462474206/blue-mark_cnzgry.png" alt="Dispute Bills">
  </a>


            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>               
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't show an image and the brand looks fine on my screen

Comment: Sorry about that. The code has been updated to reflect what I'm talking about.

Comment: Any suggestions? Thank you!